# D3.js multiple multiline charts on a page with mouseover

Tags: d3.js

I have drawn multiple charts on a page with mouseover code as shown below
[image: chart with mousever]

The problem is the data displayed on the mouse line belongs to chart2.  Moreover, mousing over chart2 creates the line in chart1.  The code to build these is one large loop.

```
                var dataset = objects[object].dates;
            dataset.forEach(function (d) {
                if(interval === 'hourly') {
                    var date_parts = d.date.split(/[-|\s|:]/)
                    d.date = new Date(+date_parts[2], (+date_parts[0] - 1), +date_parts[1], +date_parts[3], +date_parts[4]);
                }
                else {
                   var date_parts = d.date.split(/-/);
                   d.date = new Date(+date_parts[2], +date_parts[0] - 1, +date_parts[1]);
                }
                d.total = d.total / 1000000000000;
                d.available = d.available / 1000000000000;
                d.used = d.used / 1000000000000;
                return d;
            });

            var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 100},
                width = card.offsetWidth - 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 200 + margin.top + margin.bottom;

            var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                .domain([
                    d3.min(dataset, function (d) {
                        return d.date;
                    }),
                    d3.max(dataset, function (d) {
                        return d.date;
                    })
                ])
                .range([0, width]);


            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) {
                    return d.total
                })])
                .range([height, 0]);

          var xAxis;
            if ( interval === "hourly") {
                xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .ticks(dataset.length - 1)
                    .tickFormat(formatTime)

            } else if (interval === 'weekly') {
                xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .ticks((dataset.length - 1) / 7 )
                    .tickFormat(formatTime);
            }

            //Define Y axis
            var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                .scale(yScale)
                .ticks(10);

            var availLine = d3.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return xScale(d.date);
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return yScale(d.available);
                });

            var totalLine = d3.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return xScale(d.date);
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return yScale(d.total);
                });

            var usedLine = d3.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return xScale(d.date);
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return yScale(d.used);
                });

            var svg = d3.select("#" + name)
                .append("svg")
                .attr("perserveApsectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
                //.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                //.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .attr("viewBox", "0, 0, " + (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "," + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "")
                //.classed("svg-content", true)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

           svg.append("path")
                .data([dataset])
                .attr("class", name + "-line")
                .style("stroke", "green")
                .attr("d", availLine);

            svg.append("path")
                .data([dataset])
                .attr("class", name + "-line")
                .style("stroke", "red")
                .attr("d", totalLine);

            svg.append("path")
                .data([dataset])
                .attr("class", name + "-line")
                .style("stroke", "blue")
                .attr("d", usedLine);

            var color = ["red", "green", "blue"];
            var values = ["total", "available", "used"]

            var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
                  .data(values)
                  .enter()
                  .append('g')
                  .attr('class', 'legend');

            legend.append('rect')
                .attr('x', width - 20)
                .attr('y', function(d, i){
                    return i * 20;
                })
                .attr('width', 10)
                .attr('height', 10)
                .style('fill', function(d, i) {
                    return color[i];
                });

            legend.append('text')
                .attr('x', width - 8)
                .attr('y', function(d, i) {
                    return (i * 20) + 9;
                })
                .text(function(d, i) {
                    return d;
                });

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .style("font-size", ".51em")
                .selectAll("text")
                        .style("text-anchor", "end")
                        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                        .attr("dy", ".15em")
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return "rotate(-65)"
                        });


            //svg.append("text")
            //    .attr("transform",
            //        "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," +
            //        (height + margin.top + 40) + ")")
            //    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            //    .text("Date/Time");

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0 ,0)")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "axis-title")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("fill", "#5D6971")
                .text("Terabytes");

            var mouseG = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "focus")
                .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

            mouseG.append("path")
                .attr("class", "mouse-line")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("stroke-width", "1px")
                .style("opacity", "0");

            var lines = document.getElementsByClassName(name + "-line");

            var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
                .data([dataset])
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

            mousePerLine.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 7)
                .style("stroke", function (d) {
                    return d
                })
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("stroke-width", "1px")
                .style("opacity", "0");

            mousePerLine.append("text")
                .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

            mouseG.append("svg:rect")
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .attr('fill', 'none')
                .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
                .on("mouseout", function (){
                    d3.select(".mouse-line")
                        .style("opacity", "0");
                    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
                        .style("opacity", "0");
                    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
                        .style("opacity", "0");
                })
                .on("mouseover", function() {
                    d3.select(".mouse-line")
                        .style("opacity", "1");
                    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
                        .style("opacity", "1");
                    d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
                        .style("opacity", "1");
                })
                .on("mousemove", function() {
                  var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
                  d3.select(".mouse-line")
                      .attr("d", function () {
                          var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
                          d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
                          return d;
                       });
                  d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
                      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                          console.log(width / mouse[0]);
                          var xDate = xScale.invert(mouse[0]),
                              bisect = d3.bisector(function (d) {
                                  return d.date;
                              }).right;


                          var beginning = 0,
                              end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                              target = null;

                          while (true) {
                              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                              var pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
                              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                                  break;
                              }
                              else if (pos.x > mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                              else break;
                          }

                          var displayFormat;
                          if(interval === 'weekly' || interval === 'monthly') {
                              displayFormat = d3.timeFormat("%m/%d");
                          }
                          else {
                              displayFormat = d3.timeFormat("%H:%M:%S");
                          }
                          d3.select(this).select('text')
                              .text(displayFormat(xDate) + "\n" + yScale.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2))
                              .attr("font-size", ".7em");

                          return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
                      });
                    });
```

It appears that somehow each dataset needs to be associated with the right chart as far as data goes.  I'm totally stumped on the mouse line being activated only in chart1.

Comment: I would suggest that you put your code on [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to allow others to play with it. That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks.  It's part of a larger django app with ajax to a db.  I'm not sure how to break it up for use on jsfiddle.

Comment: That's because you're using `d3.select(".mouse-line")` which will select the first `mouse-line` (chart1 in your case). I would suggest you add separate ID's to the SVGs and select the `mouse-line` based on these IDs. For example: `d3.select("#chart-1 .mouse-line")`. If that doesn't work out, let me know, I'll come up with an example for you.

Comment: Since I am creating two or more charts dynamically, I changed handling the dataset variable so that now under mousePerLine is looks like data(dataset).  This gets all three lines with text but it is still attached to the wrong chart.  My "guess" is the code with mouseG are unsuitable for multiple dynamically created multiline charts.